# Draggable: false doesnt appear to be working on Google maps

Tags: google-maps, draggable

We are currently using two google maps on one page, the first one is an aerial view, and this I can turn off draggable and it works fine. The other is an internal view of the building, when I use the same code on this, it doesnt disable draggable on mobile or on desktop, I can disable scrollwheel movement, but not draggable. The code I am using is below.

```
function initialize2() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: fenway,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 8,
        draggable: false
    };
    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,
        <?php echo(isMobile()) ? 'draggable: false,' : ''; ?>
        pov: {
            heading: 180,
            pitch: 0
        }
    };
    var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'),panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: there is no draggable-option: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions

Comment: Seems a bit useless, means cant use this on mobile now then.

Comment: means that you can set it, but it will no effect anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add: draggable: false like this

```
// Function to initialize the map within the map div
 function initMap() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: { lat: 27.963989, lng: -82.799957},
     zoom: 14,
     draggable: false
   });

 }
```